# Why don't askers accept answers they up-vote and accept-in-comments?

Tags: discussion, reputation, voting, accepted-answer

Many times I answer a question (correctly) and in comments the original asker replies saying "Thanks, that worked!" and they leave, usually up-voting the answer, but not marking it as the accepted answer.  I check back even months later, and it's still the only answer posted to the question, up-voted once, but not accepted as the answer.

Is there a reason for this besides asker neglect, or is there something StackOverflow can do (further) to motivate people to Accept answers?

(I know SO displays a big red box saying "consider accepting the answer" when an asker up-votes an answer, but somehow this apparently doesn't phase most people)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It happens a lot, and I certainly get aggravated when I've got an Enlightened badge sitting on the table, just waiting for that little green check. Askers certainly get plenty of notification about it. Auto-accepting answers for anything but bounties (where one is required) is certainly not the correct solution. It's aggravating, but c'est la vie. As Ron White says, "You can't fix stupid."

Comment: LOL.  I just considered up-voting you and never coming back to this question to mark anything as accepted. :)

Comment: you certainly can't fix stupid, but you CAN fix something that every other novice overlooks.

Answer (score 7):

Why do people who don't know how to play baseball have a tendency to run the wrong direction?

Answer: because they are new.

It probably wouldn't hurt to leave a comment on their question and say "hey, if this answered your question, could you please give me the check mark" and see what happens.

Comment: I find it more efficient to run directly to third as opposed to re-routing through first and second base.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, because they're new, like TheTXI said, and might not know about this whole "accepting answers" thing. *Or* they just don't care enough for the time being — they got their answer and happily went on with their business without giving much more thought to the site (until they get hit with some other problem, of course).

Also, [as I've noticed recently](https://superuser.com/questions/14659/1-2-key-on-macosx), sometimes this might happen because the question was migrated to another SO family site, but the OP didn't follow there (as you can see from  greyed-out username), for one reason or another.